# REST based Response Status codes

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest

I'm not sure what response code to use when the request is valid but there is no result for the given parameter

The JSON returns a success of true/false and a message

When I do a `GET` and there is some data I use:

`200 HttpStatusCode.OK`

However where there is no data should I still use `OK` and return the JSON success / message or should I use `400 HttpStatusCode.BadRequest` to indicate something in the request is bad.

Comment: That depends on whether the request was actually bad, or if there were just no results to display. I'd say it's fine to return HTTP status code 200 (OK) and an empty json success message if there were no results, but the request itself was not malformed and could be read properly

Comment: How could `HttpStatusCode.BadRequest` indicate that there are no results to return? Very misleading. Bad request is a bad request - some malformed data, incorrect input values etc. Think about it that way - would you expect `List<int>.Length` throws `InvalidOperationException` if the list is empty?

Comment: Request is fine, just no data. Lets say give me person 27. But person 27 isnt part of my account or doesnt exist. Thus the Request is bad, your not requesting valid data.

Comment: You might want to decide whether you are going to fully use response codes or indicate success with a JSON message.  Indicating success with a JSON message is essentially tunneling the response status.  I would tend to do one or the other, but not mix approaches (if they mean the same thing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what does it mean for the client to not have results.
Typically lack of data would still be http 200 ok.

e.g. `/employees` etc.

However, for some scenarios you could return 
HTTP 404 Not Found.

Especially when the client expects a particular resource to be present.

e.g. `employees/update/32`

Normally any other response code (204 etc.) though technically valid and fitting, might confuse the client.
Also, 400 Bad Request should also be not used, if there is nothing wrong with the request.

Comment: In the `/employees` example, I would typically return 200 with a response of `[]`.

Comment: @Davin Both are viable options, yours is a little bit more forgiving / flexible if you're planning on supporting different clients.

Answer (score 1):

If the operation was successful but there is really no response data, use the status `204 NO CONTENT`. If an expected entity was missing, return `404 NOT FOUND`. If there was some sort of internal error, return  `500 SERVER ERROR`.

According to the [HTTP/1.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html),

> The server has fulfilled the request but does not need to return an
>   entity-body, and might want to return updated metainformation. The
>   response MAY include new or updated metainformation in the form of
>   entity-headers, which if present SHOULD be associated with the
>   requested variant.
>
> If the client is a user agent, it SHOULD NOT change its document view
>   from that which caused the request to be sent. This response is
>   primarily intended to allow input for actions to take place without
>   causing a change to the user agent's active document view, although
>   any new or updated metainformation SHOULD be applied to the document
>   currently in the user agent's active view.
>
> The 204 response MUST NOT include a message-body, and thus is always
>   terminated by the first empty line after the header fields.

Comment: heads up : this could lead to problems with clients expecting a JSON reply, but that don't special case HTTP status code 204.

Comment: I dont agree, because NO CONTENT returns NO CONTENT thus I cant return any json with any explanation.

Comment: Right.. this is meant only for those cases when the operation is successful, but there is really no data to return. If there was some sort of error, then use other response codes. I've added clarifications to my answer.

Comment: @TimothyGroote returning a body with 204 is definitely not a good idea. I'd prefer to return the correctly mapped HTTP statuses for each scenario.

Comment: I understand that. what i'm saying is that this will cause a problem with clients that don't understand status code 204, or completely ignore the status code, but do expect a body.

Answer (score 0):

If ther was nothing wrong with the request but you just don't have any data (i.e. search returns 0 rows) than I would not use `BadRequest`:

> BadRequest is sent when no other error is applicable, or if the exact
>   error is unknown or does not have its own error code.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx